# JQuery slice() not hiding/showing correctly

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slice

I have 16 elements of the class `row`

I'm trying to change the elements that are showing at one time by slicing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.row').slice(0, 2).show();
$('.row').slice(3, 16).hide();


$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.row').slice(0, 2).hide();
    $('.row').slice(3, 5).show();
    $('.row').slice(6, 15).hide();
});

});
```

So initially, you only see these three items:

```
Row 0
Row 1
Row 2
//$('.row').slice(0, 2).show(); -- this is correct
```

but then when I click my button to show the next three, instead this displays:

```
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
//yet I specified this: $('.row').slice(3, 5).show();
```

Why does this happen and how could it be fixed?

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RjHvw/

Comment: Please give a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slice method is based on zero based index, [Slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), even end parameter also is based on zero-based. the range extends up to but not including the specified index.

[See demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsW8V/1/)

Comment: Right, `slice` works with the half-open interval `[start, end)` rather than the closed interval `[start, end]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
//yet I specified this: $('.row').slice(3, 5).show();
```

That seems correct, slice index is 0 based.

You can just add `1`:

```
// just so it's clear
// you'd tipically have an `idx`
// or `counter` where you add `1`
$('.row').slice(3 + 1, 5 + 1).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said [Slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) uses 0 based index and the end numbered element is excluded from the selected list. Here is the argument definition in jQuery.com which says this

> .slice( start [, end] )
>   startAn integer indicating the 0-based
>   position at which the elements begin to be selected. If negative, it
>   indicates an offset from the end of the set.
>
> endAn integer indicating
>   the 0-based position at which the elements stop being selected. If
>   negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set. If omitted,
>   the range continues until the end of the set.

Here is [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/NGmyZ/1/) of what you are trying to achieve